# Youtube data api token

Tags: api, youtube, authorization, token

I'm going through this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php and I have come to a problem at step 4. I have ran the `quickstart.php` and got the link to the code, but I accidentally pressed "enter" without typing in the code. Now if I run it again I get an error:

> PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken.

I understand i can't make another token, i just would like to know how do I delete this token and make a new one.

Comment: Replaced image with text, minor corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I had to delete php-yt-oauth2.json file in home directory, which was declared here: define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/php-yt-oauth2.json');.